# Implement 16 bits stored Goertzel algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I can detect the frequence of 8 bits stored PCM audio in Goertzel algorithm, C language.
Now I want to detect 16 bits stored PCM audio, C language as well. But when I change the code to 16 bits I found it not work well as 8 bits one.
I'm not very familiar with this Goertzel and many years not touched FFS something like that. Is there someone share some code/link or info to help implement this 16 bits one in C language? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you got? I wonder if you could post your working 8-bit code and not quite working 16-bit code for people to look at. Otherwise, have you tried searching the internet for sample code for your purpose.

Comment: Hi FooF, thanks. I'm referring the code [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=183683) to implement my 16-bit detection. But unfortunately, no output after changed input from 8-bit(unsign char) to 16-bit(short), which means detecting wrong. Can you please help to judge this program can work for 16-bit or not? Thank you.

Comment: You could try make the `unsigned char` that is used for PCM data a `typedef`, have a conditional code to switch between `unsigned char` and `short` (or better still, use `#include <stdint.h>` and `int8_t` and `int16_t` if your C compiler is new enough). This way the transition is easier to manage - the same source code with different `typedef` produces 8-bit or 16-bit PCM support. It allows perhaps easier to see where something does not go well (integer arithmetic).